# Inclusive Disability

Tags: game-recommendation, conditions

There is a tendency for games to treat physical handicaps/neurodiversity as either flaws or outright punishments. While I understand that a character losing an arm, their sight, or their freedom of movement is traumatic for that character, I don't think it accurately represents either the mythos of RPGs/fantasy in general or the real-world capability of those of us with disability. The archetypal blind monk, blade-handed barbarian, or even a withered wizard in a wheelchair are common enough that it seems anachronistic *not* to have this kind of representation.

I always identified with Raistlin's chronic health issues, and in more recent years I've had more characters adopt cosmetic limps or mental processes similar to my own. However, representation for disability or accommodation seems rather lacking in even modern settings.

Is there a setting or established set of mechanics that exists that could both:

- Avoid reducing disability to a series of points, as in Flaws: these still have a connotation of being a cost the character pays, and thus undesirable rather than neutral or empowering
- Avoid shaming or punishing disability mechanically, as that would often be cultural rather than any sort of ingrained requirement for many disabilities

Comment: Hi T BG, and welcome to the site. Check out our [tour] to see how we work. I'm closing this since we no longer facilitate recommendation requests for products, such as games or campaign settings; they don't work well in our format. You can however ask for those on a forum [such as one of these we've made a list of](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449). I empathise with your goal though, and it's laudable, and there are systems available for this. You may also join us in [RPG General Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) to talk about this if you'd like.

Comment: Could you be more prescise in what you miss about the way disabilities are featured? - Especially, could you point to something that is not featured "as a series of points" but is still integral to the games core?   ----- And: could you expand on how a dis-ability, i.e. an ability that is absent, would not be punished mechanically, without that dis-ability disappearing (as in: not make an appearance)?

Comment: I've not had something to 'miss', since I've not had experience within a system which adequately portrays this. Aspects from Fate may seem alright, going forward.

As an example, I have arthritis, leading to severe pain in my legs and back even out for a stroll. I still engage in regular martial arts, renaissance fencing, and when friends need a couch moved it will be me they call: I've learned not just to cope but to excel in some ways. Autism is often depicted as mental penalties, but depending on presentation this may be wrong - it may lead to INT, WIS, or even CHA boosts (assuming D&D)